# Page Navigation to Activity after PayUMoney transaction in Android

Tags: android, payumoney

I am developing a sample application with PayUMoney Transaction. The app functions well. But I am looking for redirecting the page to an Activity after the transaction. Does anyone gone through this? Please guide me.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using PayUMoney SDK ?

Comment: I am using native code with webview sample from this link http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2015/06/payumoney-integration-example-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to open activity once you received SUCCESS_URL or FAIL_URL as below :

```
if (url.equals(SUCCESS_URL)) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Success! " + url,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//open activity here 
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failure! " + url,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//open activity here
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note:
>
> isOverrideResultScreen=false : PNP will take care of Transaction
> result screen. isOverrideResultScreen=false : Merchant will have to
> take care of Transaction result screen.

```
PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(paymentParam,
this, R.style.AppTheme_default, isOverrideResultScreen);
```

Hope this helps!

For more information refer https://developer.payumoney.com/android/